# Migrate SQL Server data to Neo4j and keep data in sync for both the databases

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2008, neo4j

How to migrate data from SQL Server to Neo4j without using `LOAD CSV`?

Other tools do not give a complete transformation as per schema but just a sample (ex: ETL). If there is something that could be done with a node js application that would be great.

Also how to keep the data in sync between SQL Server and Neo4j?

Comment: apoc.load.jdbc is your friend ... check it out

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options here:`apoc.load.jdbc` is one option, there is also `neo4j-etl-components` project.

**apoc.load.jdbc**

There is capability for connecting to a relational database and streaming the results of SQL queries to Neo4j from within Cypher available in the [APOC procedure library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures).

For example:

```
// Create Product nodes
CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/northwind?user=root","SELECT * FROM products") YIELD row 
CREATE (p:Product {ProductID: row.ProductID})
SET p.ProductName = row.ProductName,
    p.CategoryID  = row.CategoryID,
    p.SupplierID  = row.SupplierID
```

More info is available in the [docs.](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_load_jdbc)

**neo4j-etl-components**

`neo4j-etl-components` is a tool that will

1. Inspect an existing relational database schema
2. Apply rules to this schema to convert to a property graph model
3. Optionally, provides a GUI interface for editing how this translation should be applied
4. Stream export from the relational database to create a new Neo4j database (offline batch) or online incremental insert into Neo4j.

`neo4j-etl-components` can be used as a command line tool. For example, to run an initial batch import:

```
~: $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-etl export  \
  --rdbms:url jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:49161:XE \
  --rdbms:user northwind --rdbms :password northwind \
  --rdbms:schema northwind \
  --using bulk:neo4j-import \
  --import-tool $NEO4J_HOME/bin  \
  --csv-directory /tmp/northwind \
  --options-file /tmp/northwind/options.json \
  --quote '"' --force
```

See the docs [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-etl-components/) and Github page for the project [here.](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-etl-components)

**Keeping in sync**

Once you've done the initial import of course you need to keep the data in sync. One option is to handle this at the application layer, write to a queue with workers that are responsible for writing to both databases, or run incremental versions of your import with `apoc.load.jdbc` or `neo4j-etl-components`.